# How to echo an environment GitHub variable to a yml file in a workflow

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions

I have created a new environment in GitHub and created a new env var with Oktokit,
Now I want to use this variable in a yml workflow file
I read the documentation but I couldn't really understand what am I doing wrong.

The [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context) says the following this:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
env:
  # Setting an environment variable with the value of a configuration variable
  env_var: ${{ vars.ENV_CONTEXT_VAR }}
```

Now, my code looks like this:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
env:
  # Setting an environment variable with the value of a configuration variable
  last_automated_release: ${{ vars.LAST_AUTOMATED_RELEASE }}
```

....

```
  - name: Echo env var
    run: |
      echo "variable from shell environment: $last_automated_release"
      echo "variable from shell1 environment: ${{ env.last_automated_release }}"
```

No matter what I receive an empty string in the CI

I know the variable contains data:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

This is the workflow I am using:

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 10 * * *'
  workflow_dispatch:
env:
  CHANNEL: 'cloud'
  CHANGELOG_FILE: 'temp-changelog.txt'
  # Setting an environment variable with the value of a configuration variable
  last_automated_release: ${{ vars.LAST_AUTOMATED_RELEASE }}

jobs:
  display-variables:
    name: Display Variables
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    environment: SCHEDULE_RELEASES
    steps:
      - name: Dump all data types
        run: |
          echo "vars ${{ toJson(vars) }}"
```

Comment: Are you configuring that variable under a specific environment? If yes, are you configuring the correct `environment` in your workflow? Please include the rest of your workflow in your question.

Comment: @Azeem couldn't understand how to configure the variable under the environment I created.
The environment is called `SCHEDULE_RELEASES`  I have added the entire workflow content to the question.

Comment: Your workflow looks fine. You just need to verify if `LAST_AUTOMATED_RELEASE` is configured under `SCHEDULE_RELEASES` environment or not. You may refer to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#creating-configuration-variables-for-an-environment to verify the steps that you followed to add it.